# Having difficulty to bind elements value without listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my page I want to insert a value to the elements inside my page from code behind. This is my code behind and I want to add each label or image and it's value without gridview or listview or datalist. The code below need to be update as it's not working so I help from you guys.

I have to create a screen record and I have update my post above I hope that will explain what I am looking for :-)

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSsqtFwXQL4&feature=youtu.be)

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try {

            SqlConnection showads = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand CMDshowads = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ads where AdsID = @AID", showads);
            SqlDataReader adsdetread = CMDshowads.ExecuteReader();


            int i = 0;
    while (adsdetread.Read())
    {

        Image imgthum1 = new Image();
        imgthum1.ID = "Img1" + i;
        imgthum1.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img1"].ToString();

        Image imgthum2 = new Image();
        imgthum2.ID = "Img2" + i;
        imgthum2.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img2"].ToString();

        Image imgthum3 = new Image();
        imgthum3.ID = "Img3" + i;
        imgthum3.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img1"].ToString();

        Image imgthum4 = new Image();
        imgthum4.ID = "Img4" + i;
        imgthum4.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img2"].ToString();

        Image imgthum5 = new Image();
        imgthum5.ID = "Img5" + i;
        imgthum5.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img1"].ToString();


        Label adstitledetailsshow = new Label();
        adstitledetailsshow.ID = "adstitledetailsshow" + i;
        adstitledetailsshow.Text = adsdetread["AdsTit"].ToString();

        Label Label1 = new Label();
        Label1.ID = "Label1" + i;
        Label1.Text = adsdetread["AdsID"].ToString();

        Label Label5 = new Label();
        Label5.ID = "Label5" + i;
        Label5.Text = adsdetread["AdsPrice"].ToString();

        Label Label11 = new Label();
        Label11.ID = "Label11" + i;
        Label11.Text = adsdetread["Website"].ToString();

        Label Label2 = new Label();
        Label2.ID = "Label2" + i;
        Label2.Text = adsdetread["Section"].ToString();

        Label Label4 = new Label();
        Label4.ID = "Label4" + i;
        Label4.Text = adsdetread["Category"].ToString();

        Label Label6 = new Label();
        Label6.ID = "Label6" + i;
        Label6.Text = adsdetread["Country"].ToString();

        Label Label7 = new Label();
        Label7.ID = "Label7" + i;
        Label7.Text = adsdetread["State"].ToString();

        Label Label8 = new Label();
        Label8.ID = "Label8" + i;
        Label8.Text = adsdetread["City"].ToString();

        Label Label3 = new Label();
        Label3.ID = "Label3" + i;
        Label3.Text = adsdetread["UID"].ToString();

        Label Label10 = new Label();
        Label10.ID = "Label10" + i;
        Label10.Text = adsdetread["AdsDate"].ToString();




        //add your controls here.

        container.Controls.Add(imgthum1);
        container.Controls.Add(imgthum2);
        container.Controls.Add(imgthum3);
        container.Controls.Add(imgthum4);
        container.Controls.Add(imgthum5);
        container.Controls.Add(Label1);
        container.Controls.Add(Label5);
        container.Controls.Add(Label11);
        container.Controls.Add(Label2);
        container.Controls.Add(Label4);
        container.Controls.Add(Label6);
        container.Controls.Add(Label7);
        container.Controls.Add(Label8);
        container.Controls.Add(Label3);
        container.Controls.Add(Label10);



        i++;
    }
  }
  catch 
  {
     adsdetreqLikeqpopup.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use one of the ASP.NET repeater controls then you should make all your control dynamic yourself. So basically you need a container for your controls first, let's say a DIV tag on your page like this (*remember to add runat and id properties in there*):

```
   <div runat="server" id="container"></div>
```

then inside the while loop you could just have something like this:

```
        int i = 0;
        while (adsdetread.Read())
        {
            //your images
            Image img1 = new Image();
            img1.ID = "img" + i;
            img1.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img1"].ToString();

            Image img2 = new Image();
            img2.ID = "img" + i;
            img2.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img2"].ToString();

            //rest of your images here

            //your labels
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "lbl" + i;
            lbl.Text = adsdetread["AdsID"].ToString();

            Label lbl2 = new Label();
            lbl2.ID = "lbl" + i;
            lbl2.Text = adsdetread["AdsID"].ToString();

            //rest of your labels here


            //add your controls here.

            container.Controls.Add(img1);
            container.Controls.Add(img2);
            container.Controls.Add(lbl);
            container.Controls.Add(lbl2);

            //add the rest of your controls here

            i++;
        }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

to check your string values before assign them to the controls you could do something like this on each line:

```
img1.ImageUrl = adsdetread["Img1"] != null ? adsdetread["Img1"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

**Update 2:**

There is a missing part in your sql command, that you didn't set the value of **AdsID** your sql part should be look like this:

```
 using (var connection= new SqlConnection(cs))
 {
     using (var command = new SqlCommand())
     {
         command.Connection = connection;
         connection.Open();
         command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ads where AdsID = @AID";
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AID", your value here);

         using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             int i = 0;
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 //....
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: many many thanks for your answer, i have do as you mention but the label didnt show any data at all you can see my update of my post, and i get error message: 'Image' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' and 'System.Drawing.Image'

Comment: Ok, first of all you must check the value of your database before you assign them to a control in your code behind, and about the error it's because you have two namespaces declared on your page then it recognizes the image object as an ambiguous object at run time, so to resolve it instead of  `Image img1 = new Image();` you could write `UI.WebControls.Image img1 = new UI.WebControls.Image();`

Comment: thanks for your reply i have record my screen to show what i am facing please could you watch and gives me your opinion:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALSHNr8pQMw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You must set the sqlcommand parameter in your code, check the second update for a better understanding

Comment: many thanks, but please could you explain to me how i can add the value in correct way ("@AID", your value here) sorry but i am not so familiar with C# like you

Comment: Your `AdsID` value is the selected value id from the selected image or row on your web page, you must grab that Id and set it to your query. otherwise the query won't work without the id. for example something like this: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AID", AdsID.text);`

Comment: I really appreciate you kind help i couldn't find some one like you to help me with my problem, i have do and i wish is correct but still doesn't work i have upload a new screen record and i wish if you can find it: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFnlnOV7RJQ&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Ok, I think you need to read more about [ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET) before you want to go further. The number of parameters must be match with your sql query: in this query *SELECT * FROM ads where AdsID = @AID* you only have one parameter which is AdsID and that's it. you cannot set any other parameters unless you have more parameter in your query. The value of AdsID must come from  its selected data row.

Comment: Hi @Ali Shahrokhi i have change my sql statement but i get others errors too so i think there is no way to solve it throw this discussion, so i am sorry to bother you and many many thanks for your help